What is the difference, if any, between "en bas de casse" and "en minuscules"?
I read on https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigle:

On notera que certains sigles très répandus et de prononciation aisée (acronyme) peuvent se composer en bas de casse avec capitale initiale : Benelux (sans accents), Euratom, Unesco, etc.

What is the difference, if any, between "en bas de casse" and "en minuscules"?

Bas de casse and capitale are part of the typography vocabulary.
The letters they describe are classified according to their actual shape. The haut de casse letters (i.e. uppercase) were stored in the upper part of the casse and the bas de casse (lowercase) were stored in the lower part of it.

   Manuel de l'imprimerie, Casse de Gillé, 1817.
Outside a typesetting context, i.e. in real life, we call the former majuscules or capitales  and the latter minuscules.
The nuance between majuscules/minuscules and capitales/bas de casse relates to text rendition versus grammar. The capitalization rules require for example that a proper noun starts with a majuscule letter followed by minuscules, e.g. France.
These rules are independent of what will actually be done when typesetting a document. For example, someone might want to write that proper noun only with capital letters FRANCE, perhaps with smaller ones after the initial letter like this: Fʀᴀɴᴄᴇ, or even only using lowercase letters france.
Whatever their choice, the F remains technically a majuscule and the other letters minuscules.

Very clear, thanks!

In grammar, we only distinguish between majuscules and minuscules. The actual faux-ami is that, in France, we commonly use the grammatical terms whereas the anglophones use the typesetting ones.

@ jlliagre Very interesting answer!

@mins Je ne comprends pas l'objet de ton commentaire. Est-ce une suggestion de correction ou d'amélioration ? Une citation qui confirme ma réponse ?

Je pense que "The nuance between majuscules/minuscules and capitales/bas de casse is grammatical." est ambigu. Majuscule/minuscule sont des éléments de la langue écrite, mais capitale/bas de case/lettrine/petite capitale/ligature/filet/espace de ponctuation, etc appartiennent à la chose imprimée, et sont inconnus de la grammaire. Cette graphie d'imprimerie utilise des éléments typographiques qui ne sont pas des majuscules mais des capitales et une lettrine, ce que vous écrivez vous-même par ailleurs.

@mins D'accord. L'ambiguïté était pour moi levée par le paragraphe suivant mais je vais tenir compte de ta remarque. Merci.

Vous pouvez aussi observer qu'à l'exception du é, les minuscules accentuées sont en principe composées avec des caractères du haut de casse (le é aussi dans la casse de l'Imprimerie nationale), besoin que l'on ne retrouve pas pour la langue anglaise et où la relation lettre minuscule --> composée en bas de case est plus naturelle.

@mins Oui, c'est vrai, les minuscules sont stricto sensu des haut de casse mais je dirais que c'est un peu anecdotique. Ces minuscules accentuées et d'autres caractères sont déjà bien visibles dans le graphique inclus dans ma réponse. PS: On se dit tu.
